# How to get Google API code for brand account?

Tags: google-api, youtube-api

I'm wondering whether there is a simple way to get an Google API key for a YouTube brand account It seems that you can only get an API code for the main account. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Voted to close, for being off topic.

Comment: @aussiejoe  you don't have the reputation to vote something off topic.

Comment: API keys are for accessing public data you can get one in Google developers console.  private data you will need to use oauth2.